# Afford credentials within a PowerShell script to be executed

Tags: powershell

I have the follwing code that I want to execute but when I run it, a window pops up asking me to enter credentials, how can I pass insert credentials within the script so that the script is executed without the pop-up window

The $user and $pwd are afforded from another script

Below is the PowerShell script

```
Param(
$user
$pwd
)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$user = 'Beta'
$ADS = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties DistinguishedName | select 
DistinguishedName
$null,$OUS= $ADS -split '(?<!\\),',2
$domain = $ADS -split ","|?{$_ -like "DC=*"}
$domain = $domain -join "."-replace ("DC=","")
$domain = $domain.TrimEnd('}')
schtasks /Create /S Client.$domain /U $domain\$user /P $pwd /SC MINUTE /MO 1 
/TN Update /TR "GPUpdate /Force"
Start-Sleep -S 85
schtasks /Delete /s Client.$domain /U $domain\$user /p $pwd /tn Update /F
```

Comment: Where do you get the credential request? I suspect it;s the Get-ADuser commandlet but if you post the error it will clarify this. Get-ADuser has a -Credential parameter. Passing credentials to this parameter has been explained in multiple questions here on SO.

Comment: It is not an error , a windows called `Windows PowerShell credential request` shows up asking to enter Useraname and Password

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinghuishedName` or `(Get-ADUser -Identity $user).DistinguishedName` to get the distinguished name as string to do the `-split` on. Anyway, since you are not using the `-Server` parameter, I guess you are on the same domain as the user you are giving in the $user parameter. In that case, you can create the domain\user part for the scheduled task much easier with: `"$($env:USERDOMAIN)\$user"` and skip the Get-ADUser and domain name splitting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing schtasks with the relevant PowerShell functions. They support [CIM Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/new-cimsession?view=powershell-6) (for dealing with passwords) and will be much easier to use (passing arguments and sorting through returned data).

1. Set-ScheduledTask https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps
2. Unregister-ScheduledTask https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-delete-scheduled-task/